# Python pandas datetime casting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, casting

I am having troubles with the casting to datetime in pandas.

Step 0:
Start file

[image]

Step 1:
I import the file with pandas dataframe.  Nohting fancy, just

```
def xls_to_df(myfiles):
    frames = [pd.read_excel(file) for file in myfiles]
    for i in range(len(myfiles)):
        myfiles[i] = Path(myfiles[i]).name
    df_all = pd.concat(frames)
    helper.logger.info("Import %s records in dataframe from files %s", len(df_all), myfiles)
    return df_all
```

Step 2: Changing formats

```
mydf['Datum_temp'] = pd.to_datetime(mydf['first_known_date'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
mydf['Datum'] = pd.to_datetime(mydf['Datum_temp']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Now the date is the correct format (dd/mm/yyyy), buth it needs to be datetime64ns.
How do I change this AND keep the format (dd/mm/yyyy) and dtype on export to Excel.

I tried multiple things but I always end up with either the correct format with an object or the wrong format with datetimens64.

Once I have this, how do I keep it when merging with an another dataframe?  It seems that the datatypes get lost after merging.

Comment: `I tried multiple things but I always end up with either the correct format with an object or the wrong format with datetimens64.` - yes, you are right. It is impossible in python datetime object with custom format

Comment: Is there another way?  I also tried on export.  I am using pd.ExcelWriter.
format_datum = workbookSTL.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yyyy'})
worksheetSTL.set_column(1, 1, None, format_datum)
Doesn't seem to work ... .

Comment: Ig need merge need same formats in both dataframes, it means both are datetimes or both are objects (strings)

Comment: _"Now the date is the correct format (dd/mm/yyyy), buth it needs to be datetime64ns."_: datetime64ns has no format. Just transform for Excel-export only, in a temporary dataframe.

Comment: @Timus: don't know how: ,I always end up with dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00 as datetime64ns OR dd/mm/yyyy in a string.  And it really has to be a datetime-field in the exported Excelfile.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually fixed it with openpyxl.

```
def fix_datetype(myxlsfile):
    file = op.load_workbook(myxlsfile)
    print(myxlsfile)
    sheets = file.sheetnames
    print(sheets)
    sheet = file[sheets[0]]
    print(sheet)
    rows = sheet.max_row
    for i in range(2, rows + 1): 
        cell = 'B' + f'{i}'
        old_date = sheet[cell].value 
        value = datetime.datetime.strptime(old_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
        sheet[cell].value = value
        sheet[cell].number_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy;@'
    file.save(myxlsfile)
```